# Bootstrapping Drupal from the command line

Tags: bootstrapping

Here is what I'm trying to do :

1. Write a php script that import external data into drupal.
2. Run that script every night with a cron that executes it using `php`, not `wget`.

In other words, I need my import script to run from the command line.

First step is done and working great when run as a module from Drupal. So I took all required bits of it, created a new file, and bootstraped drupal. After fixing a few warnings and errors (path issues mainly), the file is executed but actually no job is done.

So I start adding echo commands to see where everything goes to hell. And it appears that it's right after

```
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

What I mean is that no error, warning or whatever is raised, but it's like the script exit somewhere inside that call.

I tried to lower the boostrap level to DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_LANGUAGE, but then I get the following error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function field_info_field() in /www/includes/entity.inc on line 768

I'm a bit lost on what happens and would welcome any suggestion.

Also, here is the beginning of the script that bootstrap Drupal :

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    chdir('/www/');

    $cmd = 'index.php';
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']       = 'default';
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']        = '/index.php';
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']     = '127.0.0.1';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = NULL;
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  = 'GET';
    $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']    = '';
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']        = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/';
    $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'console';    

    define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/www/');
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_LANGUAGE);

    // nothing gets executed past this point
    print("0\n");
```

Comment: For anyone who would run into the same issue, I ended up doing what Damien suggested (using drush). Unfortunatly, our drupal setup seemed a bit unstable and drush would not run. So I installed a blank drupal to run drush from, and changed the running DB with db_set_active

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't even try this. Use `drush`, it is meant for this type of things precisely.

The `drush php-script` command will allow you to run any PHP script in the context of Drupal, but I would recommend writing those as a proper command inside a custom module.

Comment: Actually the cron is doing far more things than just calling the php script. It's connecting to a remote FTP, download the sql dump, import it to a local database, backup the drupal database, do the import into drupal, and then cleanup on succes or restore + log + mail on error.

Tbh, if we good have inserted the data directly in the drupal db, without leveraging drupal, I'd be happy. But we need the drupal API. 

What I also want to avoid is curling a drupal module to make the cron work. 

Why can't we use the bootstrap for this ? it seems to be designed for that kind of thing.

Comment: @SebastienF.  I think you missed a a key point here.  If you call 'drush php-script myimporter.php', then it will run just like it was called from Drupal.  drush takes care of all of the quirks of doing a bootstrap from the command line.

Comment: Oh ok, didn't understood it like that. Will try asap and update accordingly.

Comment: Installed drush, made a simple test (node_load(21)), getting the "Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_load()", tried everything I found so far (putting the script in default site directory, calling the script from the root drupal directory, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Damien. Trying to invoke the bootstrap is not the way to go.

If the data you are importing is in csv or xml format, I would suggest you use the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module. It is tailor made for this and you can schedule it as a daily task.

Comment: The data are in an external database, there's quite a lot of them to process, and for everything described in the comment I added on Damien's answer, I'd rather avoid doing this from drupal but rather doing it from the command line.

Comment: There is the [Feeds database](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_db) module which is an add-on fetcher. Once the local db has been loaded from the dump, it might provide a simpler way of mapping the content creation. I like command line too, but sometimes it is really more efficient to let drupal handle the mappings to the various tables. You can still use drush to invoke the process.